# Graphql Schema Not Working

Tags: graphql

I am using graphql and creating a schema

```
schema @expand(template: "Dream") { query: Ignored }

type MySchema implements Topology {
  id: ID!
  name: String!
  description: String
  location: String 
  exists: Boolean
}
```

The problem is while i am using the exists i cannot able to save the data into the schema. But, schema creation is successfully happening.

I am geeting

> 504 (Gateway Timeout)

But, if i am changing the exists to some other name then it's working. Any body knows why this is happening.

Comment: This looks like an HTTP error code to me. What is the interface you use?

Comment: @FabianPijcke i am using angular 2 as interface. Yes its HTTP error code only. But,i cannot able to figure out why i am getting while using "exists: Boolean" only. If i am using "exixts1: Booelan" then i am not getting the error.